# How does Adi Shankara refute the idea of dualism between Brahman and the Atman?

Tags: brahman, adi-shankaracharya, atma, reference-request, argument

How does Adi Shankara refute the idea of the Atman and Brahman being separate? Does he use the Upanishads for proof or does he use logic/reasoning to prove the identity of the Atman and Brahman being the same. If he has used any arguments can you present them or tell me them?

Comment: Sankara does not need to refute as the vedas say they are the same. The upanishads are veda.

Comment: @SwamiVishwanamda yes they do say that but can you please put the appropriate verses from the Upanishads that say the Atman and Brahman are the same?